# Why is an error not produced when following the Recess 'Controlling the Controller' doc?

Tags: recess

According to the section 'The Controller-View Relationship' located in http://www.recessframework.org/page/controlling-the-controller :

> Try removing the body of the printIt method and refresh to get an error indicating no view template at 'helloWorld/views/printIt.php' can be found.

I tried this and upon refreshing the page, saw `[]`. I checked the response header and it was of type application/json. Could this have something to do with it? I've tried installing Recess on another machine and it resulted in the same behavior.

Can someone tell me how to get an error???

Comment: That tutorial is pretty old and Recess has had several changes since. Make sure you have the !RespondsWith Html annotation set on the class.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction! I can finally move beyond that point in the tutorial now!

Comment: @ryanday Try posting as an answer? :)